# How to graph $\frac{x}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ and calculate its limit as $x\to 0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Suggest me good methods for proving the $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \dfrac{x}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ and how could I graph this function ?

Comment: The function $\frac{x}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ is undefined on $[0,1)$.

Comment: Your [original formulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2364812/1) was _'the limit of [x] upon x when x tends to zero'_. Do you mean $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\lfloor x\rfloor}x$ then...?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no way to "graph" a limit. We graph functions, a limit (if it even exists) is just a single number.

Second, a **Hint**:

The function $x\mapsto [x]$ is constant on $(0,1)$ and on $(-1, 0)$.

This means that the limits

$$\lim_{x\downarrow 0}x^{[x]}$$
and $$\lim_{x\uparrow 0}x^{[x]}$$

are very easy to calculate. So, answer the questions in order:

1. if $x\in(0,1)$, what is the value of $[x]$?
2. if $x\in(0,1)$, what is the value of $x^{[x]}$?
3. What, then, is $$\lim_{x\downarrow} x^{[x]}?$$

Comment: sorry that was wrongly edited

Comment: now approach to my question

Comment: @BORNTOLEARN There's still a mistake.

Comment: i am new to this site i am not comfortable with the writing please correct it i actually want to ask X UPON GREATEST INTEGER FUNCTION OF X

Comment: @BORNTOLEARN Do you mean $x^{[x]}$? You write that as `x^{[x]}`

Comment: @BORNTOLEARN Or maybe $\frac{x}{[x]}$? That can be written as `\frac{x}{[x]}`

Answer (score 1):

Well, since intuition is crucial in mathematics, we will first graph our function $f(x)=\frac{x}{[x]}$. To do so, consider that $[x]$ is constant on every interval of the form $[n,n+1)$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and has the value of $n$. So, $f$ will not be defined over $[0,1)$, since there $[x]=0$ and on every other interval, it will be a part of a line with a slope of $\frac{1}{n}$. The graph shoiuld be something like:

[image]

So, now we can easily see that the limit
$$\lim_{x\to0}[x]\equiv\lim_{x\to0-}\frac{x}{[x]}$$
should be equal to $0$. To prove this, let $\epsilon>0$. For $x\in[-1,0)$ we have that - since $x<0$:
$$f(x)=-x$$ so, let $\delta=\min\{\epsilon,1\}$. Then we have:
$$0-x<\delta\Rightarrow x>-1\Rightarrow |f(x)-0|=f(x)=-x=0-x<\delta\leq\epsilon$$
So, we have shown that:

$$0-x<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-0|<\epsilon$$
hence,
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$$

Comment: i edited it now try it.

Comment: Allright, give me some time. :)

Comment: I' ve given a new answer, hope this helps! :) Oh, for your - and our - convenience, use MathJax next time! :)

Comment: yeah i got it. graph is really awesome

Comment: No, function is not defined at $0$, it is defined at an interval that is a neihbourhood of zero and, hence, we can talk about $f$'s limit as $x\to0$.

Comment: yes now i understood

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's about
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\lfloor x\rfloor}x$$
consider two intervals: $x\in (-1,0)$ and $x\in (0,1)$.

How can you simplify the function $\frac {\lfloor x\rfloor}x$ in each interval?

Does it have a limit at $x\to 0$ from each interval separately?

Are those limits equal?

Comment: yeah its good method but i am asking just its reciprocal.

Comment: @BORNTOLEARN Yes, I know that -- now. But when I decided to write my answer, your question was so ambiguous that I started from its [original, first version](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2364812/1), which apparently was mis-formulated. Anyway I don't think it's worth fixing, as Vasilis Markos has already given an answer which is good, thorough and, last but not least, on-topic.